# Запуск игр на отдельном Х-сервере (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: ubuntu

Хочу запускать игры на отдельном Х-сервере, т.к. при сворачивании игр из Вайна, они падают. Подскажите новичку как все сделать.Пользователи добавлены, все открыто. Только нужен файл запуска.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну дык перед запуском

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Ну вы поняли ...

Comment: Нет, к сожалению. Можно поподробнее? Или пример файла./home/dima_m/Euro Truck Simulator 2/bin/win_x86/eurotrucks2.exeЕсли нужен путь

Comment: Ну вот хоть бы постаралась понять, идея в том что бы перед запуском указать на какой дисплей направить приложение , делается это посредством переменной  $DISPLAY. Т.е >export DISPLAY=:0 && wine /home/dima_m/Euro Truck Simulator 2/bin/win_x86/eurotrucks2.exe

Comment: Просто я на убунту меньше года, не все знаю. И терминал выдает ошибку. Не хочет запускать.Я читал на форумах, что запускают через исполняемый файл игру. Но так и не вышло. Так обидно, уже все перепробовал, что нашел.Простите за тупость :)